# CakePHP: Joining calculated fields from another model to a model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've been trying to figure out how to add some computed fields to a model in CakePHP. I'm able to achieve the desired result with the following query:

```
SELECT project_id, 
    COUNT(*) AS clicks_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN clicks.redirect_url = projects.url THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS clicks_redirected,
    SUM(CASE WHEN clicks.redirect_url = projects.url THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS clicks_not_redirected
FROM clicks
LEFT JOIN projects ON clicks.project_id = projects.id
GROUP BY project_id
```

If I attempt to execute it as a custom query Cake transforms the result in such a way that it would require much array manipulation to be usable. I tried to do it the Cake way with the following code, but for some reason the calculated fields end up in a separate array which causes strange behavior in the view:

```
$this->paginate = array(
'Project' => array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id', 'name', 'url', 'url_mac', 'url_mobile',
        'COUNT(*) AS clicks_total',
        'SUM(CASE WHEN Click.redirect_url = Project.url THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS clicks_redirected',
        'SUM(CASE WHEN Click.redirect_url = Project.url THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS clicks_not_redirected'

        ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'clicks',  
            'alias' => 'Click',  
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Click.project_id = Project.id')  
        )
    ),
    'group' => 'project_id'
));

$this->set('projects', $this->paginate());
```

Produces the following result:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Project' => array(
            'id' => '508705c8-126c-48f9-bd9a-6d79d13bb9ea',
            'name' => 'Test Project',
            'url' => 'http://www.test.com',
            'url_mac' => 'http://www.mac.com',
            'url_mobile' => 'http://www.mobile.com'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'clicks_total' => '80',
            'clicks_redirected' => '35',
            'clicks_not_redirected' => '45'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Project' => array(
            'id' => '508b1073-2aa8-4895-b8d9-152ed13bb9ea',
            'name' => 'Another Project',
            'url' => 'http://another.com',
            'url_mac' => 'http://anothermac.com',
            'url_mobile' => 'http://anothermobile.com'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'clicks_total' => '134',
            'clicks_redirected' => '70',
            'clicks_not_redirected' => '64'
        )
    )
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas for getting the calculated click counts to show up under the Project array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add virtual fields to your model:

Check it out: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1608/Virtual-fields

> In Project model:
>
> public $virtualFields = array('clicks_total' => 'COUNT(*)');

Comment: `public $virtualFields = array(
  'clicks_total' => 'COUNT(*)',
  'clicks_redirected' => 'SUM(CASE WHEN Click.redirect_url = Project.url THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
  'clicks_not_redirected' => 'SUM(CASE WHEN Click.redirect_url = Project.url THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)'
 );`

Comment: Is it possible to define virtual fields only for a certain method? When I added the virtual fields to the model that broke all the other methods.

Comment: You can create it on the fly in the controller before your find:
`$this->Project->virtualFields = array('clicks_total' => 'COUNT(*)');`